# Makefile executes if and else

Tags: gnu-make

The question is short actually.

This:

```
$(info Param: $(1))
ifneq (,$(findstring String,$(1)))
    $(info FOUND)
else
    $(info NOT FOUND)
endif
```

Produces this:

```
Param: ThisIsMyString
FOUND
NOT FOUND
```

Why, where is the problem which I am not getting?

Comment: Works on my machine. Only printing NOT FOUND. The `$(1)` suggests this isn't the full makefile, so you should add that to the question. Also add the command to produce the output. For reference I ran `make`.

Comment: Agreed.  Almost 100% certainly you're using this inside another variable which is being invoked via `call` or `eval` or both.  That's what's expanding things: you need to escape things you want to be delayed.  You'll have to put the full context here in your question if you want us to be able to help you, not just an extract that works properly by itself.